Receiving "TypeError: setUser Is Not A Function, (It Is Undefined), But Its Listed As A Const
There's no other details after that message,but when I attempt to login/register, I'm seeing the "console.log" pop up successfully. Firebase is also receiving the info as well
Here is my Register.js file
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import React from 'react';


import LoginPage from './LoginPage';
import { authentication } from './Config';
import { useAuth } from './AuthContext';

export default function RegisterPage({navigation}) {

  const [email, setEmail]  = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
  const {user, setUser}= useAuth();

  const signUp = () => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(authentication, email, password)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('You Have Successfully Created An Account!');
        setUser(res.user);
      })
      .catch((re) => {
        console.log(re);
      })

   }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Welcome! Create Your Account Here</Text>
      <TextInput style = {styles.input}
       keyboardType='email-address'
       placeholder='Please Enter Your E-Mail Here'
       placeholderTextColor={'#aa336a'}
       value={email}
       onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
    />
     <TextInput
     style = {styles.input}
     placeholder='Please Enter Your Password Here'
     placeholderTextColor={'#aa336a'}
     secureTextEntry
     value={password}
     onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
  />   
  <TextInput
     style = {styles.input}
     placeholder='Please Confirm Your Password Here'
     placeholderTextColor={'#aa336a'}
     secureTextEntry
     value={confirmPassword}
     onChangeText={(text) => setConfirmPassword(text)}
  /> 
  <Button title='Create An Account'  onPress={signUp}></Button>
  <Button title='Not Your First Time Here?' onPress={() => navigation.push('Login')}></Button>
</View>

);
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: '#ffb3c6',
   alignItems: 'center',
   justifyContent: 'center',
 },
 input: {
 width: 340, 
 height: 57,
 backgroundColor: '#d6b4fc',
 alignItems:'center',
 justifyContent: 'center',
 marginTop: 17
},

});
As well As my Login.js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Alert, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import React from 'react';
import RegisterPage from './RegisterPage';
import { authentication } from './Config';
import { useAuth } from './AuthContext';

export default function LoginPage({navigation}) {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const {user,  setUser } = useAuth();

  const inputRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();




  const signIn = async () => {

    signInWithEmailAndPassword(authentication, email, password)
      .then ((res) =>{
        console.log('You Have Successfully Signed In!');
        setUser(res.user);
      })

      .catch ((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setError('Error In Signing In')
      })

  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Welcome Back! Please Sign In</Text>
     <TextInput
         ref={inputRef}
         style={styles.input}
         placeholder='Please Enter Your E-Mail Here'
         keyboardType='email-address'
         placeholderTextColor={'#aa336a'}
         value={email}
         onChangeText={(email) => setEmail(email)}
      />
       <TextInput
         ref={passwordRef}
         style= {styles.input}   
         placeholder='Please Enter Your Password Here'
         placeholderTextColor={'#aa336a'}
         value={password}
         secureTextEntry
         onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
      />
      <Button title='Login' onPress={signIn}></Button>
      <Button title='First Time Here?'onPress={() => navigation.push('Register')}></Button>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    width: 340,
    height: 57,
    backgroundColor: '#d6b4fc',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 17
  },
});

I tried turning the curly brackets into an array, but that caused an error that wouldn't cause the page to load
Edit: This is the AuthContext.js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider =({children}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
        {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
export default AuthContext;


Where is the AuthContext code?

I tried to add it in the comments, but it keeps showing up as one continuous paragraph. Is there a way to format the comment or just create a new question?

can you add it to the body of the post?

Thank you so much for the suggestion! I just added it

Have you wrapped your components in the AuthContext.Provider anywhere?
